# I want to count total records in a table using impala and store it into a file .But not sure how to do it

Tags: python, shell, hive, hiveql, impala

I have a list of table in a file : `tables.txt` 
contents is:

```
db.tab1
db.tab2
```

and so on
Now I am passing it to a function and counting the number of records in each table.

```
def rec_count(table_name):
    impala_cmd_cnt = "impala-shell -i %s -q  'select count(*) from %s'"%(impala_node,table_name)
    impala_cmd_res = os.system(impala_cmd_cnt)
```

impala_cmd_res contains the execution code i.e 0 for succes and non-zero for failure. 
But I want to store count of the table in a variable .How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer . I was able to get the output of above command using 
`subprocess module` .

```
show_create = "impala-shell -i  %s -q 'show create table %s'" % (impala_node, table_name)
        impala_show_cre_res = subprocess.Popen(show_create, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        create_out = impala_show_cre_res.communicate()
```

create_out contained the output . So I used the regex to scrap out the needed  from the output.